# How do I count the multi column in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

First of all, thank you in advance for your help.

I have 4 types of products. I want to count the unsold products of these 4 types of products. How can I do it?

I want to run this query with a single query.

```
SELECT urun_id,urun_tipi,urun_satildimi FROM urunler WHERE urun_tipi = 1 and urun_satildimi = 0;
SELECT urun_id,urun_tipi,urun_satildimi FROM urunler WHERE urun_tipi = 2 and urun_satildimi = 0; 
SELECT urun_id,urun_tipi,urun_satildimi FROM urunler WHERE urun_tipi = 3 and urun_satildimi = 0;
SELECT urun_id,urun_tipi,urun_satildimi FROM urunler WHERE urun_tipi = 4 and urun_satildimi = 0;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT` to get total rows and `IN` filter to merge your queries into one.

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN urun_tipi = 1 THEN "Product A"
    WHEN urun_tipi = 2 THEN "Product B"
    WHEN urun_tipi = 3 THEN "Product C"
    ELSE "Product D"
END,
COUNT(1)
FROM urunler
WHERE urun_tipi IN (1,2,3,4)
AND urun_satildimi = 0
GROUP BY urun_tipi;
```

Comment: product_type means each different product. I want to print each one separately.

Example: product_type = 1 as ProductA, product_type = 2 as ProductB

Comment: @alon3wolf, try the updated query in my answer.

Comment: Samir you are perfect! Thank you very very very much <3

Comment: Glad to help :). Just a suggestion; SO will be able to help you even better and faster if you post an expected output along with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `IN` for filtering:

```
SELECT urun_id, urun_tipi, urun_satildimi
FROM urunler
WHERE urun_tipi IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND urun_satildimi = 0;
```

Comment: product_type means each different product. I want to print each one separately.

Example: product_type = 1 as ProductA, product_type = 2 as ProductB

Comment: @alon3wolf . . . There is no such logic in the query that you purportedly want to combine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the count, you should use COUNT() with GROUP BY. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM unruler
GROUP BY urun_tipi,urun_satildimi
ORDER BY urun_tipi DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) Product types are mixed. I want to separate product_type = 1 as ProductA, product_type = 2 as ProductB. https://prnt.sc/12ztkiq

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
    urun_tipi,
    COUNT(*)
FROM urunler
WHERE urun_tipi IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND
      urun_satildimi = 0
GROUP BY urun_tipi
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to count the remaining stocks of each product separately.

urun_tipi = 1 and urun_satildimi = 0 // Procut A (remaining stock)
urun_tipi = 2 and urun_satildimi = 0 // Procut B (remaining stock)